# Inkscape with TexText

Tags: latex, text, inkscape

I am trying to install the package TexText on Ubuntu, such that I can type Latex in certain gaphs. I followed [these](http://www.timteatro.net/2010/08/05/textext-for-math-in-inkscape/) instructions, but when I open Inkscape I do not have the option Latex in the Extensions menu... Can anyone help me diagnose this problem?

Comment: You could make the question clearer by explaining what exactly you did sofar. Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: @landroni In the link I provided the procedure is outlined. I did exactly that. I can retype it here but I don't really think that is necessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I installed TexText and it works fine for me. I am using UBUNTU 13.10 and Ink-scape version 0.48

Here what I have done:
=> First install Inkscape
=> Download latest TexText version from [here](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/)

=> Now extract downloaded *tar.gz* file and copy all files inside *~/.config/inkscape/extensions/*
=> Now ***pstoedit*** extension is require to install (Go to `Ubuntu software center` > Search for `Inkscape` > Click on <kbd>More info</kbd> > Scroll down > Under Optional add-on `pstoedit` can be found > Check it > Click on <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd>)
[image]

=> Restart `Inkscape` and Now you can see `Tex Text` option under `Extension` menu. Select `Extension` > `Tex Text`
[image]

=> Open Gedit or your any favourite text editor.

Type

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

Save as `anyname.ini`

=> Now inside `TexText`

1. For `Preamble file` browse and select `anyname.ini`

2. Change Scale factor if you want. I changed it to `6.50`

3. Inside text paste any latex text such as

```
\begin{Large}
Hello world!
Have you yet checked out my new integral equations?
%
\begin{small}
 \[ M^\bot = \{ f \in V' : f(m) = 0 \mbox{ for all } m \in M \}.\] 
\end{small}
%
\end{Large}
```

4. Click OK and That's it
[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the thorough reply!

Comment: I don't understand the part about `pstoedit`.  Can you explain it using command-line ?  I'm using Lubuntu LXDE which lacks the Ubuntu Software Center.