# Textext install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: latex, inkscape

I am trying to install `textext (0.4.4)` in `inkscape (0.91 r13725)` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Unfortunately, the `Tex Text` item is not showing under the 
`Text` item in the Extension menu.

I followed step by step the instructions at https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/ .

---

Here is what I did :

- Using the "Ubuntu Software Center" I checked that the following libraries are installed : pstoedit texlive full python-lxml
- Using the new "Ubuntu Software" (Ubuntu 16.04), I installed inkscape
- Inkscape seemed to be working perfectly. I closed it
- I downloaded from https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/ the textext-0.4.4.tar.gz and extracted textext.inx and textext.py
- using "sudo cp" I moved the two files into ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/
- I launch inkscape. However the "Tex Text" item is not showing in the "Extensions" menu (I have inkscape in French).

---

I tried to reboot my computer. I checked the inkscape `extension-errors.log` file. I even try to move the `.inx` and `.py` to the `/usr/share/inkscape/extensions` folder.

I am running out of ideas; could it be linked with the python 2-> python 3 shift in 16.04?

**I used the same procedure on Ubuntu 14.04 and I got textext working perfectly**. This is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer to my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646948/installing-textext-0-4-4-in-inkscape-0-91).

It seems the `~/.config/inkscape/extensions` folder can only be accessed with root priviledges. Therefore, by default, when inkscape is launched it won't be able to load the extensions.

I downgraded the root priviledges of every files in the `/extensions` folder using :

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/*
```

`Textext` is working just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem too. I am using Inkscape 0.91. I found this link very useful if you are doing this for the first time:
[Inkscape with TexText](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417212/inkscape-with-textext)